# Get the Current Users password from the login and pass it to a Bash script

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04

I am writing a Bash script in Linux to remote in to a Windows box. I would like to capture the current user and password for that user so that the script will log them in to the TS session. I am making a thin client with Linux.

Comment: I don't think you can capture the password, that would be a serious security problem. You can ask user to enter it again, though.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid the system does not know your password. Never. It only knows some sort of hash of your password. It is the nature of hashes that they can not be turned back into clear text. If you type your password, the system uses the same hash function as was used to create password and compares the hashes. So capturing the password: first: bad idea to have it float around in a costume made bash script in clear text, unless you are absolute security expert on linux and know what you are doing. Second: Quite impossible to do, for good reason.

However there are other ways to do a passwordless login. For example `SSH/SSH-Server` offers authentication with a public/private key system. Or you can use a single sign on environment like it is possible with kerberos. Since the second option is quite overkill if it does not already exist on your network, go with ssh keybased auth. There is a [question on askUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46930/how-can-i-set-up-password-less-ssh-login) about this. You will need to find a sshd for windwos though. Wikipedia [lists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_SSH_servers) a few. This will most likely limit your access to the windows box to the text console.

For gui-logins you might want to poke around with `Krdc` or `Remmina`. But I don't know how well you can interaget them into a script leave alone passwordless login.

Comment: The "system" must remember the login password for at least a little while, not just to hash it and see if it's correct, but to decrypt an encrypted home too. I think it uses PAM for that, so there is a way to have PAM use the password for other things too...

Answer (score 0):

Type the command in the terminal

```
$ sudo apt-get install zenity
```

then you want to make your bash script with the following content:

```
zenity --password
```